# How to properly port this code to Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, pubnub

PubNub offers this snippet in the iOS SDK to call some client methods before the clients gets suspended as a result of the app resigning from active:

```
- (void)pubnubClient:(PubNub *)client willSuspendWithBlock:(void(^)(void(^)(void(^)(void))))preSuspensionBlock {

if ([client isConnected]) {

    preSuspensionBlock(^(void(^completionBlock)(void)){

        [client sendMessage:@"Hello my friend" toChannel:[PNChannel channelWithName:@"boom"]
        withCompletionBlock:^(PNMessageState state, id data) {

            if (state != PNMessageSending) {

                NSString *message = @"Message has been sent";
                if (state == PNMessageSendingError) {

                    // Handle message sending error
                }

                // Always call this block as soon as required amount of tasks completed.
                completionBlock();
            }
        }];
    });
}
}
```

Now XCode is smart enough to convert the crazy blocks syntax in the method declaration to this, which I guess is fine:

`public func pubnubClient(client: PubNub!, willSuspendWithBlock preSuspensionBlock: (((((() -> Void)!) -> Void)!) -> Void)!)`

I really can't figure out how to port this line though:
`preSuspensionBlock(^(void(^completionBlock)(void))`

Blocks syntax was always killing me.

Comment: Same for me... Did you find anything?

Comment: If your problem is with background, i finally use "shouldRunClientInBackground" for use correctly pubnub with background...

Answer (score 0):

The objective-c code is a preSuspension method accepts a block that returns a block that accepts no arguments. Try something like this:

```
  var x: (()-> () -> Void) = { () -> ()->Void in
        return {() -> Void in
            println("this is returned inner void block")
        }
    }

    preSuspensionBlock(x);
```

Answer (score -1):

PubNub.sendMessage(chatMessage, googleCloudNotification: nil, toChannel:chatChannel, storeInHistory: true) { (state, obj) -> Void in

```
       if (state != PNMessageState.Sending){
          println("Message has been sent")
         if(state == PNMessageState.SendingError){
           completionHandler(responseStatus: RespStatus.unExpectedServerError)
         }
         else{
            completionHandler(responseStatus: RespStatus.responseSuccess)
        }
       }

    }
```